# Mysql SELECT UNION returning wrong results?

Tags: mysql

I have this single query.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE type!='' AND (page_option='0' OR page_option='1') ORDER BY type ASC";
```

The first three results for the column `scenario` returned are `a1`,`d3`,`e1`.

Now when i do a UNION ALL with other identical tables:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `my_table` 
                    WHERE type!='' AND (page_option='0' OR page_option='1')
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT * FROM `my_table_2`
                    WHERE type!='' AND (page_option='0' OR page_option='1')
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT * FROM `my_table_3`
                    WHERE type!='' AND (page_option='0' OR page_option='1')
                    ORDER BY type ASC";
```

I loop through the results and the first three columns for `my_table` are `e1`,`e1`,`e1`.

Each table has a column called `type`, which identifies the table the result comes from.  So for the union query results i added a condition to display only scenarios from `my_table`

```
if($type=="my_table") {
  echo $scenario;
}
```

The scenarios should be identical to the single query but they aren't.

How do i solve?

Comment: Can you share some sample data with what is expected  output  and what actual output  you are getting?

Comment: i did, the first three results in the single query should be identical to the first three results in the union query but they aren't.

Comment: You can make the alias of each table `SELECT t1.* FROM my_table as t1` to identical the data.

Comment: I can't follow your problem statement.  Show us, via some sample data and output, what is going on here.

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption is wrong. Order Isnt guaranteed unless you use `ORDER BY`

In your case you are order only by `type` so the order of other fields can be random

You can find a nice explanation and examples here:

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/05/20/without-order-by-there-is-no-default-sort-order.aspx